# customize listbox in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, listboxitem

This maybe easy but I have no clue where to start. I parse xml value and bind them to listbox; for better interface, I want my the item display in different background colors. Item1 has background color is green, Item2 has background color is white, item3 has bg is green, item4 is white and so on.

Listbox
   Item1: bg green
   Item2: bg white
   Item3: bg green
   Item4: bg white

What approach should I take to achieve this?
My code as below:

```
                        <ListBox Name="listbox1" Height="502" Width="448">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>

                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="15,10,25,10" OpacityMask="#FF33A82D" Background="#FFBEFFBE" Width="480">
                                        <Image x:Name="imageAV" Source="Images/album_art_default_small.png" Height="100" Width="100" 
                               Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="0,0,15,0" />
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding track}" FontWeight="Bold" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,5" Foreground="Black" />

                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding artist}"  Width="Auto" Foreground="Black"/>

                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding album}"  Width="Auto" Foreground="Black"/>
                                        <StackPanel.Background>
                                            <SolidColorBrush />
                                        </StackPanel.Background>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    </StackPanel>                                  

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                    </ListBox>
```

code:

```
    void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(e.Result))
        {
            int[] counter = { 1 };
            string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Stream str = e.Result;
            str.Position = 0;
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(str);

            var data = from query in xdoc.Descendants("rank")
                       select new ranking
                       {
                           index = counter[0]++,
                       //    avlink = (string)query.Element("album_gdo").Element("avlink"),
                           album = (string)query.Element("album"),
                           track = (string)query.Element("track"),
                           artist = (string)query.Element("artist"),
                       };          
         //   lb1.ItemsSource = data;   
            listbox1.ItemsSource = data;
        }

    }
```

Thanks bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are couple of links with information on how to use databinding and converters. You will need to use IValueConverter to databind to "index" property of your items.

[Data binding in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
[Data binding and value converters](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/30/format-data-in-silverlight-databinding-valueconverter.aspx)

Here is an outline of what it may look like

```
<StackPanel Background="{Binding index, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}">
```

and your ColorFormatter can look something like this:

```
public class ColorFormatter : IValueConverter
{
    string[] colorArr = {"Red","Blue","Green","Yellow"};
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (colorArr[(int)value % 4]);
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This you mean ColorConverter instead of ColorFormatter? What is the index and how the index will pass to the class to get the color?

Comment: I look online that we have to add namespace and stuff, I have no clue how to do that? Can you help me clarify it a bit?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that there's a property in the object you're binding to that can indicate this, you should bind that property to the background of the item (in the template) and use a converter to turn it into the appropriate brush.